# How can I show the output that show true and false value follow by each year?

Tags: python, pandas

They want me to compute, print, and plot the number of booking by years and checked-in vs. cancelled.

[It has to show output like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Giket.png)

```
pd.crosstab(df.arrival_date_year, df.is_canceled,margins = True)
```

This is all I can do but it doesn't work.

How can I show the output with the expect output. (I'm not good at English, sorry.)

Comment: what is the input? please provide an example (as text)

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zfXlLgXvHAOHEIRv3ILAMLIOfc56S4bU/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.